# check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version

Tags: php, mysql

can't figure out what's the problem with this code

keep getting error on

> Notice: Undefined index: userID in C:\wamp\www\myProject\editProfile\edit_save.php on line 10

and

> Could not run query: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(UserID, matrix_num,student ,username ,town ,email , txtFavorite,noDate,txtMobil' at line 1

```
if($_GET) {
$noEdit = $_POST[''];
              //"SELECT *FROM "
$sql        = "SELECT * FROM tblmyprofile where student='$name', username='$username', matrix_num='$matric', town='$town' and                   mail='$email'";
$query      = mysql_query($sql, $masuk,$boleh) or die ("Gagal query".mysql_error());
$data       = mysql_fetch_array($query);
}
```

Comment: What is `$sql` when you get that error?

Comment: are you sure this query is the one generating the error?

Answer (score 2):

The comma operator is invalid in the WHERE clause.

It looks like you wanted logical `AND` or `OR` operators. A query of the form something like this:

```
SELECT t.* 
  FROM tblmyprofile t
 WHERE t.student = 'fee'
   AND t.username = 'fi'
   AND t.matrix_num = 'fo'
   AND t.town = 'fum'
   AND t.mail = 'foo'
```

But that's a very odd construct for a SQL query; there's nothing invalid with it. But usually, with SELECT, we're usually intending to retrieve rows based on a few predicates, and then getting the values from the row back.

For debugging issues with SQL queries, it's often a good idea to string together the SQL text you intend to send to the database, and then echo (or printf or vardump) the string, e.g.

```
$sql = "SELECT col, expr, col FROM mytable WHERE col = 'abc'";
echo $sql;
```

Then, reference `$sql` in the call to parse and execute a SQL statement.

I believe part of the issue you are encountering may be the construction of the string containing the SQL text. Some languages are persnickety about including variables and quotes within string literals.

e.g.

```
$sql = " WHERE t.fee = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($foo) . "'"
     . " AND t.fi = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($bar) . "'"
     . ...  ;
```

Again, after you put together the SQL text, echo it out for debugging, and verify that it's the string you intend to send to the database.

---

Also note that the **mysql_** interface is deprecated. New development should be using **mysqli_** or  **PDO**. Also note that including any unsafe variables in SQL text can lead to SQL injection vulnerabilities. Either "escape" special characters in variables you include in the SQL text, or better, use prepared statements with bind parameters, to avoid SQL injection.